# System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar memory use with a large maximum value

Tags: c#, .net, memory, max, trackbar

I have a control that contains a System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar. I was setting its maximum value to ~200,000,000. When I did this, the control required 800MB of memory. Reducing the maximum value to 2,000,000 used a more reasonable amount of memory.

```
//trackBar.Maximum = 210554060;  // uses ~800MB of memory
trackBar.Maximum = 1000000;      // uses a small amount of memory
```

Is this a bug in the Windows control? Or am I asking the trackbar to do something unreasonable?

**Update:**
I've created a new Windows Form project with nothing but a trackbar on the form. I set the maximum value to 200,000,000. I set the TickFrequency and changes so that there are not millions of ticks and change steps.

When I do this, the application uses over 800MB of memory. I am using .NET Framework 4.

[image: trackbar max set to 200,000,000, using > 800MB memory].

**Update**
I found somewhat of an explanation for this problem: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms.controls/2006-12/msg00015.html

**Adding link to test project**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh6jsymw05feoqn/testingTrackbar.zip?m

Comment: How did you determine that it uses a huge amount of memory?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206654/excessive-memory-usage-by-comctl32-dll-when-a-checkbox-controls-visible-becomes)

As far as narrowing it down to the TrackBar, I changed the trackbar's maximum to 1000000 and used the Resource Monitor tool to view Commit memory. I suppose I should make sure the problem isn't something else using that maximum value.

Comment: Well, I've just done a noddy reproduction, and the maximum size makes no difference at all to my app. I doubt therfore that it's actually the trackbar that's using that much memory. Have you bound something to the trackbar maximum value?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue I've reproduced in a new project and have the same result. See the update.

Comment: Can you post the project (with compiled exe) somewhere to see if we can reproduce on another setup?

Comment: A very interesting point here, when I made an app to reproduce this, I couldn't. (I added an obscenely large trackbar as outlined here to an existing scratch project). Today, I start up said project, and it's cripplingly slow and large. How odd that restarting visual studio makes the issue show itself! Although not surprising reading @Hans Passant answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the Windows control?

Yes, I think you can call that a bug.  Particularly nasty on a 64-bit operating system with the platform target set to AnyCPU so there's no reasonable upper-bound on the memory allocation.  My machine completely died a swapping death with mouse and Ctrl+Alt+Del unresponsive, I hard-booted it to get it back.  Thanks.

Two bugs actually.  It starts with the native track bar control not putting a reasonable upper limit on the number of ticks.  You can survive that in design mode by assigning the properties in the right order.  But it is compounded by a flaw in the TrackBar class wrapper, it assigns the Maximum property *before* the TickFrequency property when it initializes the native control at runtime.  So for a brief moment it still has a gazillion ticks.  Well, it is not brief when it is 2 billion of them, like I unwittingly tried.

No simple fix for this and this bug isn't going to get fixed.  Use reasonable values, you can always map them by multiplication.